# Dropdownlist to always fire action regardless on selectedvalue being changed or not in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `dropdownlist` and want for the dropdownlist to keep firing the action whenever I selected a value, regardless of the selected value being changing or not.

> dropdownlist having value of (a, b, c)

```
dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //action adding a new row in gridview
}
```

In this case, if I select the `dropdownlist` value (a, b, c, a, b,...) respectively this still works.

However, if I select the `dropdownlist` value (a, a, b, c, c, a,...) respectively, (a,a) and (c,c) doesn't fire the action.

This clearly does not work as I wanted, as it only works whenever I select a different value.

How do i play around this? Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example of your code where this is occurring

Comment: Show your page_load code

Comment: OK it is now clearer, the event fires as expected .... which is **on selected index changed**. This is the desired behavior.

Comment: Why do you want to trigger a postback when nothing has changed?

Comment: It is how it should have worked, but not what I want. I'm planning to make a list of `(a, b, c)` with different `numbers`, along with different id for each combinations. Thus, why I really need that whatever I click in the `dropdownlist` gets recorded, regardless of it changing value from the previous one or not @Jon P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedIndexChanged` event only fires when the `Value` is different. In this first snippet, there are duplicate `Value` items, so selecting the first or second `A` makes no difference and the event is not fired.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So make sure you have unique values, something like this and it will work.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A_1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A_2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B_1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B_2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C_1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C_2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```